# How to Read and Display specific information from a text file from user attached file without saving into database in PHP or Javascript?

Tags: preg-grep

please help a brother!

I'm writing a script to be able to read user's .txt file in order to search a specific keyword, say "model number" and display in the textarea of my html page. I wanted to achieve this extraction on real-time base, i.e the the PHP Function `preg_greg` should accept attach file variable(dynamic) NOT static as appeared here `preg_greg('config.txt')` without saving the file into the dbase. following are both my php and javascript codes, respectively.

PHP:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="?">
        
    <div>
        <input type="file" name="file">
        <textarea cols="30" rows="20">
            <?php
        $lines = file('config.txt');
        $lines = preg_grep("/Jibrin/i", $lines);

        foreach($lines as $name){
            echo "$name";

    }
?>
        </textarea>

    </div>
    
    </form>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
let input = document.querySelector('input');
let textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');

input.addEventListener('change', () => {
    let files = input.files;

    if(files.length == 0) return;

    const file = files[0];

    let reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = (e) => {
        const file = e.target.result;
        const lines = file.split(/\r\n|\n/);
        textarea.value = lines.join('\n');
    };

    reader.onerror = (e) => alert(e.target.error.name);

    reader.readAsText(file); 
    
});
```